# is stepping on the gas while gear is on P(ark) spoil the car?

Tags: automatic-transmission, accent

my car is a hyundai accent 2020 automatic transmission.
my father often step on the gas pedal even if the gear stick is on P. I think he got use to do that in a manual transmission car or he just like to hear the engine sound when revving it up. I find it so annoying.
will this spoil my car if this is done often ? or it has no effect at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This won't damage the car.**

A mechanic often revs the engine to test things.

If you rev the engine to max and leave it running at max for hours then it will suffer damage, but few do that.

Comment: ok , so if  the gear stick is on "Park" or "Neutral" mode on an automatic transmission car, it won't damage the car if you step on the gas if you just want to hear the engine roar ?

Comment: @sasori edited... just don't do it in drive...

Comment: what do you mean by , "just don't do it in drive" ? ... we step on the gas pedal when the gear stick is on "D" drive right ?..i didn't get what you mean

Comment: If you are looking under the bonnet and not sitting in the car driving properly, then stepping on the gas when in drive can cause an accident - seen it happen when someone knocked the selector from N to D...